# Generic List View raises Attribute Error: "'function' object has no attribute '_clone'

Tags: python, django

An odd error here, perhaps someone can help track down source as it's attempting to extend the Django CMS project & attempts to use uses some logic written as part of that project which I'm not fully clear on. In short, using:

```
urls.py
======================
from django.conf.urls.defaults import *
from cmsplugin_flat_news.models import News

'''RETURNING _CLONE ERROR WHEN IMPLEMENTED
def get_news():
    return News.published.all()

news_dict = {
    'queryset': get_news,
}

news_list_dic = {
    'queryset': get_news,
    'paginate_by': 50,
}
'''
# NEXT SECTION FUNCTIONS BUT NEEDS SERVER RESTART TO SEE NEW POSTS.
#CHANGING TO JUST News.published.all RAISES SAME ISSUE AS USING WRAPPER
#SOLUTION ABOVE. SEE: http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#caching-and-querysets
#& EXAMPLE HERE: http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/generic-views/#adding-extra-context

news_dict = {
    'queryset': News.published.all(),
}

news_list_dic = {
    'queryset': News.published.all(),#SAME ISSUE
    'paginate_by': 50,
}

urlpatterns = patterns('django.views.generic.list_detail',
    (r'^$', 'object_list', news_list_dic),
    (r'^(?P<page>[0-9]+)/$', 'object_list', dict(news_list_dic)),
    url(r'^(?P<slug>[-\w]+)/$', 'object_detail', news_dict, name='news_view'),
)

models.py
======================
class PublishedNewsManager(models.Manager):
    #Filters out all unpublished news and news with a publication date in the future
    def get_query_set(self):
        return super(PublishedNewsManager, self).get_query_set() \
                    .filter(is_published=True) \
                    .filter(pub_date__lte=datetime.datetime.now())

class News(models.Model):
    title           = models.CharField(_('Title'), max_length=255)
    slug            = models.SlugField(_('Slug'), unique_for_date='pub_date')
    author          = models.ForeignKey(User)
    description     = models.TextField(_('Description'), blank=True)
    image           = generic.GenericRelation('NewsImage', blank=True, null=True)
    content         = models.TextField(_('Content'), blank=True)
    tags            = TagField()
    is_published    = models.BooleanField(_('Published'), default=False)
    pub_date        = models.DateTimeField(_('Publication date'), default=datetime.datetime.now())
    created         = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, editable=False)
    updated         = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, editable=False)
    published       = PublishedNewsManager()
    objects         = models.Manager()
```

See issue in comments: basically, error raised by implementing the 'correct' solution to add extra context to the views. Error is `Attribute Error: "'function' object has no attribute '_clone'"`

Trying: News.published.all instead of `News.published.all()` raises the error whether used as part of a wrapper function or directly in the queryset part of the urlpattern.

Must be missing something obvious? Think it is to do with the PublishedNewsManager not returning objects as a dictionary, or tweaking the code to correctly return the objects to the view.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `_clone` errors are a red herring caused by you passing a function as an argument to a generic view where a `QuerySet` is expected. The version of your code which passes `News.published.all()` to the generic views is correct, as generic views will try to clone the QuerySet they are given, to avoid caching the first lot of data they query for (hence the error when you pass in a function).

Your problem seems to be that your custom `get_query_set` method is returning a `QuerySet` filtered based on the current date and time when the method was called.

I can't see anything in the documentation about `filter` arguments being callable, but I did find [this ticket which suggests that `filter` can take callable arguments](http://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/11629), so try changing your manager to pass in the function to be called to get the current date/time, rather than calling it immediately:

```
class PublishedNewsManager(models.Manager):
    def get_query_set(self):
        return super(PublishedNewsManager, self).get_query_set() \
                    .filter(is_published=True) \
                    .filter(pub_date__lte=datetime.datetime.now)
```

Comment: Thanks insin, that's just the ticket!

Answer (score 0):

Well, I ain't exactly in the same use case as the OP, but I was trying to pass a RawQuerySet to the generic views and getting the _clone error, which I fixed with an ugly hack to the RawQuerySet instance.

It seems the only thing the generic view wants to do is to clone the queryset (for caching purposes?), so I had the object return a copy of itself which satisfied the call to _clone.

error:

'RawQuerySet' object has no attribute '_clone'

code:

```
from django.views.generic.list_detail import object_list

....

li_file = File.objects.raw("SELECT * FROM file_file WHERE fn like %s", [search])

#adding this fixed the _clone missing error
def clone(self):
    #return self  - this works as well.
    return copy.copy(self)

li_file.__class__._clone = clone
#end of addition

return object_list(request, 
               queryset = li_file,
               template_name = "file/found.html",
               )
```